# DATALENGTH() or ISNULL() to retrieve fields that are not null and not empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quite simply, which of the following methods is better in a `WHERE` clause to retrieve records where the `FIELD_NAME` is **NOT NULL** and **NOT Empty**

```
WHERE DATALENGTH(FIELD_NAME) > 0
```

or

```
WHERE ISNULL(FIELD_NAME, '') <> ''
```

#### Update

I have been informed that the first method gives spurious results for some types of fields... Agree?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/cc2f4021-7fdf-4f1a-b0a0-340fdb5ed0be) for some differences between `DATALENGTH` and `LEN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly,

```
select *
from table
where column <> ''
```

will give exactly the same results as

```
select *
from table
where isnull(column, '') <> ''
```

because records where the condition is `UNKNOWN` rather than `FALSE` will still be filtered out. I would generally go with the first option.

`DATALENGTH` counts trailing spaces, which a comparison with `''` does not. It is up to you whether you *want* `' '` to compare unequal to `''`. If you do, you need `DATALENGTH`. If you don't, simply compare with `''`.

Note that for `TEXT`/`NTEXT` types, comparisons are not supported, but `DATALENGTH` is.

Comment: @hvd Forgive me for questioning your very well written answer, but I am just trying to ensure I have no flaws in my code... Are you absolutely 100% certain that both of the above queries will always return the same results? If so, what is the point in the `ISNULL` function if `<> ''` matches null values???

Comment: @BenCarey `ISNULL(NULL, '') <> ''` returns `FALSE` instead of `UNKNOWN`, which becomes relevant when you negate it, as you might in more complicated queries: `NOT(x <> '')` is equivalent to `x = ''`, whereas `NOT(ISNULL(x, '') <> '')` does `x IS NULL OR x = ''`

Comment: First solution needs `ANSI_NULLS` setting to be `ON`. From Books Online (2008+): (`In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.`)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048(v=sql.100).aspx]

Comment: @BenCarey `ISNULL` is still useful in other contexts, such as `ISNULL(a, 0) + ISNULL(b, 0) + ISNULL(c, 0)`.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Thanks, I forgot about that since I haven't encountered any system where it isn't on :)

Answer (score 2):

`ISNULL` is the best approach instead of `DATALENGTH`.

Comment: Thank you, I have just been informed of this as well

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
WHERE ISNULL(FIELD_NAME, '') <> ''
```

One issue that might come up is that a record with a space in it would not be returned. Are you looking for records like that?

I'm not sure about unexpected results from DATALENGTH. I would use the ISNULL method so that SQL Server doesn't need to spend time calculating the length of the record being compared. I don't know the performance difference between the two, just a gut feeling.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one of the following:

```
where coalesce(field_name, '') <> ''
```

or

```
where field_name <> '' or field_name is not null
```

or

```
where field_name <> ''
```

The first is standard SQL (`coalesce()` is standard, `isnull()` is not).  The last is not the most obvious, but NULL will fail the comparison and it allows the use of indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does `ISNULL` not like indexed columns?

Comment: @BenCarey . . . As a general rule, wrapping a column in a function in causes any database to ignore an index on the column.  There are exceptions.  SQL Server documentation does not list an exception for `isnull()`, so my guess is that it is not an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 1):

if your "not empty" condition encompasses  spaces then i would use the `nullif`

```
select case when nullif('  ', '') is null then 'y' else 'n' end
y

declare @d varchar(50)
set @d = null
select case when nullif(@d, '') is null then 'y' else 'n' end
y
```

Comment: @BenCarey, the `case statement` was just for demonstration. My point is that `nullif` is a handy idiom for handling situations where "space-only" values and nulls are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(FIELD_NAME, ''))) <> '' will handle spaces and NULLS
```